# Is there any definition/guidelines about user experience of Apple and Google?

Tags: gui-design, guidelines, google, apple

I like the both Apple and Google user experiences. But visually they are different. Though, I need to know their basic concepts/theory about user experience.

So we will take their inspirations not copying.

Comment: iOS and Android both have official design guidelines like the iOS Human Interface Guidelines, is that what you mean? They're not quite the same as personas for the company...

Comment: I am not talking about mobile app guidelines. I am asking about user experience in web/within the device like:

- Page Navigation (Gmail & mac finder)
- Search Component (Gmail & MAC Common Search)
- Filter Component (Gmail & MAC Filter in Finder)
- Left Panel (Gmail/G+/GDocs & iTunes)

Comment: Sorry the above comment alignment is wrong. I don't know how to rectify that. Can I post new question / able to change that?

Comment: You can just integrate that text into your question using the edit button and delete the comment; if it's important it should be in the question body anyway

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is.

- Apple OS X UX Guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html
- Apple iOS Guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html
- Android UX Guidelines: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The Basic Concepts - are actually covered on [in this part](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/HIPrinciples/HIPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000353-TP6) of the Apple UX Guidelines.

They used to explain this in more detail - and it's got cut down over time.

Originally there was a very handy [reading list](http://web.archive.org/web/19990502010057/http://developer.apple.com/techpubs/mac/HIGuidelines/HIGuidelines-260.html#HEADING260-0), which used to list all the academic research which supported the interface design.  (takes a while to load as its on the Wayback Machine)